# Can't select needed packages in Xcode 15

Tags: ios, xcode

Why can't I select only the packages that I need in Xcode 15, when I add dependencies with Swift Package Manager? For example, I want to install Firebase, but I don't need all of those dependencies that come with it. There is no checkmark next to the package name, so I can't deselect it.
[image]

Comment: Just don't add them to your targets if you don't need them

Comment: When I change the target to none and scroll down, it changes back to the target. When I press Add Package it adds them regardless.

Comment:  thats a funny bug. +1 for this finding

Comment: @Answer that a bug I believe, Apple should fix it, by the way have you reported to Apple?

Comment: I wrote about this problem on the Apple developer forums, but no response.

Comment: I have reported this scroll bug via Apple Feedback Assistant, but no hope. I have never received response from Apple there although reported many and much serious bugs. Apple tries to be nice to users but not developers. @HattoriHanzō video from this "funny" bug: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18oDanwDYSQ3EXl0StbcMUqSrUlzbt17F/view

Comment: I updated to Xcode 15.1 and bug is still there :(

Comment: Situations is the same for Xcode 15.2, How it seems Apple doesn't care what you are reporting!

Comment: Still the same in March 2024. I bought a new Mac for Xcode 15 yet it continues to be the most tedious IDE. It feels like Apple should be paying me to use this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just not add them to your target.

1. Select the project
2. Select the target
3. (from the general tap) go to the frameworks, libraries, ....
4. Select the frameworks you don't want
5. hit the <kbd>delete</kbd> or just click on the minus button below
6. Confirm

[image: Demo]

You can add them back with the plus button if you need to.

Comment: This seems to work, but all the unused "Package Dependencies" are still there even if I remove all the Firebase related stuff from the frameworks section

Comment: No way to remove the additional dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an embarrassing Xcode bug.

Firstly: why all items are enabled y default? In older Xcode there was checkboxes at left side and by default selected none. Now checkboxes was removed and several tens items selected by default.

Secondly: embarrassing bug - when you set manually None and scroll down and back up, None is removed!

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18oDanwDYSQ3EXl0StbcMUqSrUlzbt17F/view?usp=sharing

Xcode version: 15.0.1 (15A507)

Reported as:  FB13445955 since https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/ is not public, we do not know hav many thousands people must report it also uselessly because we do not know if already reported.

It seems we can not omit items during adding, we must add all and later remove!

Comment: As expected still absolutely no response from apple to reported bug. If you want to waste time - report apple bug via their feedbackassistant (aka /dev/null)